# How does scikit-learn DecisionTreeClassifier handle duplicate values when determining potential split points for a continuous predictor variable?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Suppose I have a continuous predictor variable with values of 10, 20, 20, 30. I understand that the set of potential split thresholds would include {15, 25}, as these are the means of 10 & 20 and of 20 & 30, respectively. But would 20 also be included as a potential split  threshold because it is the mean of 20 & 20, or do repeated values in the sorted array get skipped?

Note that I'm **not** asking about the metric used to select the best split threshold (gini, entropy, log-loss, etc.). I'm asking about the upstream process of identifying the *potential* thresholds that will be evaluated with this metric.

My coding skills aren't strong enough to understand the scikit-learn source code, but I *think* this information might be found [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx). I cannot find anything in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) itself about this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in your example 20 is not considered as a valid split point.  Since the splits are taken as `f_i <= threshold` vs `f_i > threshold`, in your example a threshold of 20 and a threshold of 25 are actually the same anyway.

In the code that you linked (I'm looking at `BestSplitter`), after sorting the feature values, it loops through the indices `p`, but skips over those with equal values:

```py
                while p + 1 < end and Xf[p + 1] <= Xf[p] + FEATURE_THRESHOLD:
                    p += 1
```

[[source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/86c7599d996368899898349185df068c4e2c5bd7/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx#L355-L356)] (`FEATURE_THRESHOLD` is very small and handles precision issues)